# UITapGestureRecognizer on UITableview's background view not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created a `UIView` and attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I've set the view as the target of the `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I've then set the view as the background view of my table view. The problem is the `UITapGestureRecognizer` never seems to fire, even when there are no rows in my table view. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that your table view covers the background view with the gesture recognizer. Then, the table view has its own gesture recognizers, e.g. to scroll the table. Thus it will not forward gestures to your view.  
The question is what you want to achieve.  
If you really want to capture gestures before they are seen by the table view, you could e.g. insert a transparent subview over the table view, and capture the gestures there. If they are not of interest to you, then you could forward it to the table view.

Comment: Why not use `didSelectCell` instead of a tap gesture anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to create a custom view with the gesture recognizer and setting it as the `backgroundView` for the `tableView` .It is better to use a Tap Gesture Recognizer with the table view it self. Like following [image]

Here the tap gesture recognizer is connected with the table view and on tapping the table view or table view cell the event connected with the gesture recognizer getting fired(here the event is  `tableViewTapped:` ).
Unmark the `Canceled in View` check box of the tap gesture recognizer(in right panel as in the screenshot) to enable single tap selection of the table view cell.